# Trying to get the age and make it ordinal with the name of the user

Tags: java

I'm currently learning how to code and im,trying to get get the age in ordinal and the name of the user but i cant seem to find the problem even in visual studio code  the problem isnt lsited/ wont show

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Birthdaynameandage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter date of birth in YYYY-MM-DD: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();

        LocalDate dob = LocalDate.parse(input);
        System.out.println("Happy:" + getAge(dob) + "Birthday" + name);
    }

    // Returns age given the date of birth
    public static int getAge(LocalDate dob) {
        LocalDate curDate = LocalDate.now();
        return Period.between(dob, curDate).getYears();
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly ? Does it compile ? What's the output at runtime ? PS. you should declare scanner before using it....

Comment: Your mistake is to declare Scanner at the first pale before using it
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter date of birth in YYYY-MM-DD: ");

        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();

        LocalDate dob = LocalDate.parse(input);
        System.out.println("Happy:" + getAge(dob) + "Birthday" + name);
this is your solutin

Comment: This cannot cannot compile - you are using `scanner` before you create it. Is that your error? Seems trivial to fix, so I'm not so sure. Please paste the _exact_ code you have, and the _exact_ error / behaviour you get that you're confused about.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter date of birth in YYYY-MM-DD: ");

    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    scanner.close();

    LocalDate dob = LocalDate.parse(input);
    System.out.println("Happy:" + getAge(dob) + "Birthday" + name);
}

// Returns age given the date of birth
public static int getAge(LocalDate dob) {
    LocalDate curDate = LocalDate.now();
    return Period.between(dob, curDate).getYears();
}
```

this is you solution

Comment: How do i add or make the  age an ordinal number? sorry im a beginner at coding

Comment: @Keith Guevarra: 1 -> 1st, 2 -> 2nd, 3 -> 3rd, 4 -> 4th, etc.  Keep listing ordinal numbers on a piece of paper until you see the st, nd, rd, th pattern.